# How to recover unsaved code in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I had read in some large csv files which took a lot of RAM and I noticed that `Colab` crashed once and I had to rerun all the codes all over again. I had saved the `Colab` file before I went to sleep, but when I woke up the code I added the previous day was all gone. Did `Colab` not save my code? Is there a way to recover the unsaved code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you have saved the file in your **Google Drive**, I don't think it's possible to recover unsaved code. Please see: [Colab Features](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/basic_features_overview.ipynb#scrollTo=aro-UJgUQSH1) [Colab Setup](https://course.fast.ai/start_colab.html)

Comment: I have the habit of using `command + c` to save my work and it shows `saved successfully` on bottom left corner of the page. Is that actually not saved in **Google Drive**?

Comment: Then it should be saved in the Colab Notebooks folder in your Google Drive account.

Answer (score 0):

It's too late to reply. Still, there is a workspace created in the drive for every colab notebook. Click on three dots just right to the notebook name, you can see all versions of the notebook. Download your notebook from there.